# Text moving upwards in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How to move textView and CardViews upwards when it gets focused?
I have designed cards using CardView and have added some details inside a cardView like name, date. If I focus on those cards , I need to move it upwards. When it moves upwards, the cardView colors should be changed. So that user will be knowing those cards have been focused!

The same thing needed in a textview too.

[image: See the Image - CardView which I have done]

How can I do this in Android Studio?

[The text and cardViews (ie. Kindly see hack your software career from the below link)is moving upwards!](http://www.thoughtworks.com/contact-us)

Comment: I don't understand your question... when do you want the text to animate? Because on android you don't have mouse pointers...

Answer (score 0):

Link to the documentation (see states):  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Basically, you define your background as a drawable xml,there you can define different styles of background for each state (pressed, focused, default):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

So you just need to make the background you want http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html